# Task scheduler not working on live server cPanel

Tags: php, laravel, server, scheduled-tasks, laravel-8

My cron job is not working on the live server as I have set up the corn job on cPanel. I am sending notifications to users every minute. On live server I tried from terminal but not working.

Here is the code of my scheduler.

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    
    $schedule->call(function(){
        $morning_time = inpatient_prescription::whereRaw('morning_time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE <= CURRENT_TIME() AND date = CURRENT_DATE AND morning_status = 0')
        ->join('patients','patients.id','inpatient_prescriptions.patient_id')
        ->join('departments','departments.id','inpatient_prescriptions.department_id')
        ->join('wards','wards.id','ward_id')
        ->get();

        $evening_time = inpatient_prescription::whereRaw('evening_time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE <= CURRENT_TIME() AND date = CURRENT_DATE AND evening_status = 0')
        ->join('patients','patients.id','inpatient_prescriptions.patient_id')
        ->join('departments','departments.id','inpatient_prescriptions.department_id')
        ->join('wards','wards.id','ward_id')
        ->get();

        $night_time = inpatient_prescription::whereRaw('night_time + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE <= CURRENT_TIME() AND date = CURRENT_DATE AND night_status = 0')
        ->join('patients','patients.id','inpatient_prescriptions.patient_id')
        ->join('departments','departments.id','inpatient_prescriptions.department_id')
        ->join('wards','wards.id','ward_id')
        ->get();

        if($morning_time->count()!=0){
            $user1 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_primary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();

            $user2 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_secondary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();


            $new = $morning_time;
            $user1->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            $user2->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            Notification::send($user1, new SlackNotification($new));
            event(new MessageNotification('Morning time query executed'));
            Log::info('Working');
        }
        if($evening_time->count()!=0){
            $user1 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_primary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();

            $user2 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_secondary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();

            $new = $evening_time;
            $user1->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            $user2->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            Notification::send($user1, new SlackNotification($new));

            event(new MessageNotification('evening time query executed'));
            Log::info('Working');
        }
        if($night_time->count()!=0){
            $user1 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_primary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();

            $user2 = employee::select('employees.id')->join('attendant_assigns','attendant_assigns.attendant_secondary','=','employees.id')->join('inpatient_prescriptions','attendant_assigns.ward','=','inpatient_prescriptions.ward_id')->first();


            $new = $night_time;
            $user1->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            $user2->notify(new dos_reminder($new));
            Notification::send($user1, new SlackNotification($new));
            event(new MessageNotification('Night time query executed'));
            Log::info('Working');
        }
    })->everyMinute();
    
}
```

Here is the corn job command I have added in cPanel

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/thetechbond/public_html/goodhealth/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

It is not executing. Please help

Comment: Why don't you try to run your command in the console to see the output as `/usr/local/bin/php /home/thetechbond/public_html/goodhealth/artisan schedule:run `

Comment: And be sure that crond is running `service crond status`

Comment: I have run the command it is responded with running schedule command: callback

Comment: and the crond status is running

Comment: still not working

Comment: I always make those task through a dedicated command, I have never used an schedule callback. Idk what it maybe happening in your case.

Comment: When I dd my my morning_time array it is giving me 500 server error. So I started debugging and came to know that it is not getting any data from database. The array is empty. May be the problem is in the query

Comment: But the query is working fine on local